# Set the active tmux tab color

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, tmux, terminal-multiplexer

Is it possible to change the background of the active (current) tmux tab?

I'm using `tmux 1.9` on Ubuntu 15.04.

```
$ tmux -V
tmux 1.9
```

I tried to do:

```
set-option -g pane-active-border-fg red
```

But the result was not changed:

[image]

I expected the `3-bash*` to have a red background.

Comment: @jasonwryan I don't want to change the status bar foreground color but to make the current tab display a different background color.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You haven't set window active background color, you only set active panel border, try:

```
set-window-option -g window-status-current-bg red
```

Comment: Still the same -- http://i.imgur.com/3AdyVZc.png

Comment: Yes, I saved `~/.tmux.conf` and started `tmux` in a new terminal.

Comment: `xterm-256color`

Comment: Confirming that after restarting my machine this works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Or you can run `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf` to reload the tmux conf without restart.

Comment: Also, for those wondering, you can set the foreground with `set-window-option -g window-status-current-fg 'white'`

Comment: this works. :) what is the file entry?

Comment: if you're looking at this post tmux v2.9 this option will look like so `set-window-option -g window-status-current-style bg=red`

Comment: this config `set-window-option -g window-status-current-style bg=red` works in `tmux 3.2`

Answer (score 56):

In version 3.3 use the answer in comment provided [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210174/set-the-active-tmux-tab-color/518135#comment971684_210176) by @AntK.

```
set-window-option -g window-status-current-style bg=red
```

In version 2.9 You should change this options to something like:

```
# Active window title color
setw -g window-status-current-style fg=black,bg=white
```

There's an argument with a decent explanation here: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1689

And the FAQ:
https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-translate--fg--bg-and--attr-options-into--style-options

Comment: confirmed this works for 2.9a

Comment: thanks. that's the actual way to set those colors

Comment: This throws syntax error in next-3.3. @AntK's solution worked fine

Comment: Put this in your `~/.tmux.conf` and enter `:source ~/.tmux.conf` from an active session to "hot reload" it.